# How does apple store app knows my in-store location?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi, core-location

I notice when I walk into local Apple Store (the real shop), the Apple Store app on my iPhone 5s will show a welcome from the exact store (e.g. Apple Store XX where XX is a store name). I assume this app recognizes my location somehow. This store (in China) is not equipped with iBeacon yet, and after turning off BlueTooth I can still see the greetings. I continued to shut down WiFi, and restarted this app, then location and greeting is gone. Note I didn't connect to the "Apple Store" WiFi hotspot for all tests, but it definitely indicates the WiFi is relevant with the location mechanism.

So my question is: 
how can this app know I'm near to or within the physical store based on WiFi scanning?

Is it part of Core Location public API? (if yes, I should be able to do the same thing for any shop with a WiFi signal - please explain how to achieve this in details if you know).

Or instead, is Apple doing their own dirty job but rejecting others all over the world to do the same? By dirty job, I mean a mapping from SSID to the exact location while device is not connected to the WiFi.

Thanks, geeks.